# php Laravel only allow a maximum of two line breaks in a row

Tags: php, string, laravel, line-breaks, sanitization

I wonder how I can limit the number of linebreaks. What I want to do is to "sanitize" the string so that I only get a maximum of two line breaks in a row before storing it into the DB.

Right now I have this:

```
$post->comment = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '', $request->input('comment'));
```

But this will remove all line breaks and I still want to keep one or two linebreaks in a row.

```
Dummy text
(linebreak)
some more text
```

becomes this - still having one linebreak

```
Dummy text
(linebreak)
some more text
```

and

```
Dummy text
(linebreak)
(linebreak)
(linebreak)
(linebreak)
(linebreak)
some more text
```

becomes this - only showing a maximum of two linebreaks:

```
Dummy text
(linebreak)
(linebreak)
some more text
```

Comment: Try `$post->comment = preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+~', '$1', $request->input('comment'));`

Comment: try like this: `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), array('', '', ''), $request->input('comment'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `preg_replace` with `/(\R{2})\R+/` regex:

```
 ~(\R{2})\R+~
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OPhbFA/1)

Since a single linebreak and 2 linebreaks are not to be touched, we should only match 3 or more consecutive linebreaks, and only keep the first 2, that is what the regex matches.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\R{2})` - Group 1 capturing 2 linebreaks
- `\R+` - 1 or more linebreaks

The replacement contains `$1` backreference to the contents inside Group 1, re-inserting the first 2 linebreaks into the result.

[Online PHP test](https://ideone.com/vpcXGC):

```
$str = 'Dummy text

some more text

and
Dummy text





some more text';
$result = preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+~', '$1', $str);
echo $result;
```

So, use something like

```
$post->comment = preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+~', '$1', $request->input('comment'));
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could use ``str_replace`` ? I really want to since its much faster and easier on the cpu

Comment: If there was a way, I'd post. `str_replace` does not let you check the context, count the repetitions in a simple way. You would have to add more checks, and in the end the solution would work even slower than with regex.